# jQuery Kwicks navigation in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, kwicks

I'm trying to build a site a using the jQuery Kwicks plugin for the nav, and everything is working great in Chrome (my default browser), but when I open the site in IE, which is what the customer uses, the navigation gets spaces between the menu items and I cant seem to find a solution.

Here is the site:
http://www.webexplosive.com/pb_design

Side note:
I've used this plugin for another website, http://www.webexplosive.com/accu1, and it works and looks correct in every browser...very confused!

Comment: You need to inspect the elements and figure out where the padding/etc is coming from

Comment: I see spaces between the panels even in Chrome. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: Unless I overlooked it, there is no padding. That was the first thing that I looked for.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. There IS supposed to be a 2px space between panels and this is how it is displayed in Chrome, which is correct. However in IE, there is about a 100px space between panels.